# Best way/latest one for calling SOAP Web Service from Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm new for SOAP WebServices and i was wondering which one is a better and new way for calling SOAP Webservice from Spring boot App, i found below two ways.

**1st way:**
By using [WebServiceTemplate](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-soap-client-webservicetemplate/)

**2nd way:** Convert WSDL to java class and import classes to your project, there is a stub class that you can find it in converted class, you can use it to communicate with remote service just by creating the object from stub class

Could anyone please give suggestion which one is the better/latest one for calling SOAP service from SpringBoot Application.

Comment: I always use wsimport

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  wsimport means, is it by using stub classes?

Comment: Yes. that's the easiest way because it generates all the code and you don't have to write anything by your own.